# How can I do a conditional router in Koa?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-static

Currently, I am serving an HTML file and it works fine.

(I am using `koa-mount` and `koa-static` to serve an index file under the `docs` directory.)

```
app.use(mount('/docs', serve('docs')))
```

How can I do a conditional router in a different environment properly?

The following approach works but looks weird

```
// if not production
process.env !== 'production' && app.use(mount('/docs', serve('docs')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this looks more normal?

```js
if (process.env !== 'production') {
  app.use(mount('/docs', serve('docs')));
}
```

Other than a slightly different syntax, I think your general approach is sound.

You might need `process.env.NODE_ENV` though, that's the normal place to put this value.